# How to cluster different types of geometry in openlayers 6?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I need to cluster some features that have different types of geometry (Point, LineString and Polygon),
which is the best way to do that? In addition, when I zoom to a single feature which is the best way to use the appropriate style of the feature itself (say Polygon if polygon and etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cluster source must have a geometry function to handle non-point features.  The most basic would be to return a point at the center of the extent

```
geometryFunction: functionfunction(feature) {
  return new Point(getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()));
}
```

You could also use the label points (the midpoints of linestrings and the interior points of polygons).  For styling the style function should style as a cluster if the cluster contains multiple features, but if it contains a single feature style for the geometry of that feature

```
    var clusterLayer = new Vectorlayer({
      source: new ClusterSource({
        distance: distance,
        source: vectorSource,
        geometryFunction: function(feature) {
          var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
          var type = geometry.getType();
          if (type == 'Point') {
            return geometry;
          if (type == 'LineString') {
            return new Point(geometry.getCoordinateAt(0.5));
          } else if (type == 'Polygon') {
            return geometry.getInteriorPoint();
          } else {
            return new Point(getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()));
          }
        }
      },
      style: function(feature) {
        var features = feature.get('features');
        if (features.length > 1) {
          return clusterStyle;
        }
        else {
          defaultStyles.setGeometry(features[0].getGeometry());
          return defaultStyles;
        }
      }
    }),
  });
```